# How to insert the value of an element exponentially c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to insert an element into a vector from itself, the vector is growing a rate of pow(4, i) in a for loop, lets say we have vector[] = {1,2,3,4}, How can I insert the value of vector[0] in itself so after 3 iterations it would look something like this.

Second iteration
[1,x,x,x]

Third iteration
[1,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,1,x,x,x]

and so on and so on

I have tried

```
            for(i=0; i<numAttacks; i++){
                    weightGen[i] = weightGen[i];
                    weightGen[i+numAttacks] = weightGen[i];    
            }
```

numAttacks being the growth rate

Thanks

Comment: Umm.. `weightGen.push_back (weightGen[i]);`?

Comment: What is `weightGen` is it a std::vector?

Comment: _@Diego Martínez Chavira_ So what actually went wrong with your approach? What needs to be fixed?

Comment: weightGen is a std::vector @Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
int size;
for(i=0; i<numAttacks; i++)
{
    size = weightGen.size();
    for (int j = 0; j < size * 3; j++)
        weightGen.push_back(weightGen[j % size]);
}
```

This will exponentially increase the size of the array duplicating it over and over.

Comment: If `weightGen` is greater than 29 it will overflow `int`, if you are planning to have greater values for it use `long long`